# Nginx Proxy not working

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from www.impactteachers.com/teach to application.impactteachers/teach.

This way, our application form is also accessible from the following URL: www.impactteachers.com/teach/

This works fine on our current apache server with this rule:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach/>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /teach/ http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach/
    ProxyPassReverse /teach/ http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach/
```

Because we're migrating our site to a Nginx server we need to create a new rule, according to this article: [Nginx solution for Apache ProxyPassReverse](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache) and with your help so far this is the current code:

```
location /teach { 

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://application.impactteachers.com:8080/teach;
    proxy_redirect          default;

}
```

I have tested this and it still showing the same 404 error.

Comment: Any reason for `proxy_redirect off;`?

Comment: Also, I don't see `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: Hi @AlexeyTen thank you for your reply, I will try adding your suggestions. This was the code that our IT generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like that:

```
upstream teach_backend {
    server application.impactteachers.com:8080 fail_timeout=2s;

    keepalive 32;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_server_name.com;

      location /teach {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://teach_backend/teach;
        proxy_redirect http://teach_backend/teach /teach;
        #proxy_redirect default;

        #expires -1;
        #add_header Cache-Control "private";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Sivann, thank you for helping. I'm completely new to server settings and I want to make sure I don't get anything wrong, so where it says `your_server_name` this should be in my case: `server_name impactteachers.com www.impactteachers.com`? And I also noticed if I don't use the `location /teach/ {`  it tries to apply the proxy to every page that has www.impactteachers.com/teach(ers). Again thank you for helping!